# Why xterm would run only once on XQuartz?

Tags: xquartz

I have `XQuartz` running and I can open `xterm` if I have started `XQuartz` just for the first time after rebooting the machine.  However, as time passes, I cannot create new `xterms`.  So much so that if I quit current `XQuartz` and restart just `XQuartz`, I cannot get any `xterm`.  It is annoying that I have to reboot the machine just to be able to use `xterm`.

I am running OS X 10.11 El Capitan.  I'll appreciate any insight.

Here is the information from `pkgutil`.

```
$ pkgutil --file-info /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app
volume: /
path: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app

pkgid: org.macosforge.xquartz.pkg
pkg-version: 2.7.86
install-time: 1445273913
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755
```

Comment: Which version of Xquartz are you using? And, did you install it directly, or through some kind of port manager?

Comment: I am using XQuartz 2.7.8 (xorg-server 1.16.4).  It is the same version on two iMacs.  I am not sure how did I install it.  I thought I did it through App Store but it is not in there.

Comment: You can use `pkgutil --file-info /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app` to learn if it was installed by a package —possibly downloaded from http://www.xquartz.org—, or [macports](https://www.macports.org) or similar

Comment: Added info into question.

Comment: Are you able to start other X11 programs?  Try running `xlogo` or `xclock` to see if your problem is xterms, or any x11 app.

Comment: Yes, I am able to start `xlogo` and `xman`.  So, the problem is `xterm`.

Comment: I am able to start `xload` and `xeyes` as well.  I tried to start `xterm` from a terminal but that just hung up in there with no `xterm` on screen and not even in the open applications of XQuartz.

Comment: I would just try to reinstall; perhaps the `.Xdefaults` file is corrupt.

Comment: BTW, does the problem persists if you create a new user, and try to open `xterm` from it?

Comment: I have the same problem on two iMacs.  For now, I am just going to start using Terminal app on one machine.

Comment: Create a new user, and start `xterm`. Please report result. ↵ My hypothesis is that you put something related to X server in your `.bashrc` which shouldn't have been placed there but in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Is this problem fixed?

Answer (score 2):

**Using Keyboard**

After selecting/clicking on **Xquartz**, you can press **command + n** to create how many new **xterm** windows you need.

**Using Terminal App**

open a terminal app and enter the below command

/usr/X11/bin/xterm

hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience when the computer switched or joined networks. Apparently the hostname is used as part of the authentication process to determine if a client is allowed new windows, and locks that in at start time. If you get a new hostname via DHCP, these credentials become invalid. There were some settings I could do to fix it, but I don't remember them (it was not to disable X11 security completely ;-). Try to manually start an xterm from the shell prompt in the existing xterm and throw the error message into Google - that's what helped me to solve it.